# MySQL - Preventing lock wait timeout when deleting rows from self

Tags: mysql, deadlock, delete

I have a table of around 500k rows (not big data), that I need to query against itself and then delete some of the rows which don't match the filters.

At the moment my query looks like this:

```
DELETE  tmp
    FROM  `dp_flights` tmp
    CROSS JOIN  
      ( SELECT  gmf.id
            FROM  `dp_flights` gmf
            LEFT JOIN  iatas des ON des.iata = gmf.out_des_iata
            WHERE  supplier = 'goldmedal'
              AND  (out_legs > 1
                 OR  in_legs > 1
                   )
              AND  (TIMEDIFF(CONVERT_TZ(CONCAT(out_arr_date, ' ', out_arr_time),
                           des.timezone, 'Europe/London' ),
                    CONCAT(out_dep_date, ' ', out_dep_time)) > '16:00'
                      OR  TIMEDIFF(CONVERT_TZ(CONCAT(out_arr_date, ' ', out_arr_time),
                           des.timezone, 'Europe/London' ),
                    CONCAT(out_dep_date, ' ', out_dep_time)) < 0)
      ) deletable USING (id);
```

It works occasionally. Sometimes it'll `lock_wait_timeout` and other times it won't (but does take a while).

Is there a better way of achieving this?

```
CREATE TABLE `flights` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nights` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `out_dep_city` char(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `out_dep_iata` char(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `out_des_city` char(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `out_des_iata` char(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `in_dep_city` char(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `in_dep_iata` char(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `in_des_city` char(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `in_des_iata` char(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `out_flight_no` char(6) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `out_dep_date` date NOT NULL,
  `out_dep_time` time NOT NULL,
  `out_arr_date` date NOT NULL,
  `out_arr_time` time NOT NULL,
  `in_flight_no` char(6) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `in_dep_date` date NOT NULL,
  `in_dep_time` time NOT NULL,
  `in_arr_date` date NOT NULL,
  `in_arr_time` time NOT NULL,
  `price` float(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `child` float(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `infant` float(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `currency` char(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `fare_term` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `fare_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cabin_class` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `out_marketing_carrier` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `out_operating_carrier` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `in_marketing_carrier` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `in_operating_carrier` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `out_legs` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `in_legs` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `supplier` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `out_marketing_name` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `out_operating_name` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `in_marketing_name` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `in_operating_name` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `out_flight_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `in_flight_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `iata_city` (`out_dep_city`,`out_dep_iata`,`out_des_iata`,`out_des_city`,`in_dep_city`,`in_dep_iata`,`in_des_city`,`in_des_iata`),
  KEY `flight_no` (`out_flight_no`,`in_flight_no`),
  KEY `dep_in_arr_dates` (`out_dep_date`,`out_arr_date`,`in_dep_date`,`in_arr_date`),
  KEY `a_index` (`nights`),
  KEY `dp_flights_supplier_index` (`supplier`),
  KEY `carriers` (`out_marketing_carrier`,`out_operating_carrier`,`in_marketing_carrier`,`in_operating_carrier`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

`EXPLAIN` output:

```
SIMPLE  des ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    6609    NULL
SIMPLE  gmf ALL dp_flights_supplier_index   NULL    NULL    NULL    533231  Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

Comment: Show us the actual query please and an output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE \`table\`;` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE another_table;`. If you want to rename table and column names, that's fine but we need to know the indexes and which column (a,b,c,d,...) is in which table.

Comment: @ypercube updated with the real table info.

Comment: If the 3-letter cities and iatas are ascii only, use `CHARACTER SET ascii`, not `utf8`.  Ditto for concurrency.  `CHAR(3) utf8` takes 9 bytes; `CHAR(3) ascii` takes only 3.  (No, this won't solve the timeout.)

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...;` for the embedded `SELECT`.  How many rows are there in that `SELECT`?  Are there other queries hitting this table when the timeout occurs?  What are they doing?

Comment: @RickJames I've added the `EXPLAIN SELECT` output. No queries should be hitting the table at the same time.

Comment: Please provide the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for dp_flights and iata.  You are not even using `flights`, which you did provide.  There might be an incompatibility between `iata` and `out_des_iata`.  Are they the same datatype and collation?